# Laravel keep receive get method instead of post from React

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have project with React and Laravel (I keep using blade btw). Then, I want to send bunch of json data (without form tag) to Laravel.

I simply use fetch like this :

```
const data = {'_method': 'POST', '_token' : tokenCSRF, 'id': '1','name' : 'test'}
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ls-crud', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'method' : 'POST',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : tokenCSRF,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'POST'
            },
            mode:'cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
            .then(response => response)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

and the route I use is :

`Route::post('/ls-crud', [FavoriteController::class, 'crud'])->middleware('admin');`

Then, I just have simple test function in my controller like this :

```
public function crud (Request $request) 
{
    // ddd($request);
    return response()->json([
        'id' => json_encode($request) 
    ]);
}
```

I don't know where the problem is and I have tried many ways like if you see I put method everywhere, including CSRF token, even put mode cors, still it gets read as get method.

Comment: Do you have a wildcard route that takes precedence over this route?

Comment: try running `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Ca you show the result of php artisan route:list ?

Comment: I didn't use wildcard

Comment: ```php artisan optimize:clear``` didn't change anything. I also try to use ```php artisan cache:clear```, it doesn't change anything either

Comment: @Thibaut maybe you can check here https://codepen.io/rhmynt/pen/zYJKbro